# Ковид-скептик или ковидскептик?

Tags: орфография

Ковид-скептик или ковидскептик? По аналогии с бизнесменом... Отдельно мен не употребляется, поэтому слитно. Скептик употребляется, поэтому с дефисом? Или я неверно рассуждаю?

Answer (score 3):

1. Слово ***ковид*** фактически используется в прессе как нарицательное и даже образует новые слова: ***ковид-диссидент, ковид-скептик***. Они пишутся преимущественно через дефис, являясь приложениями, то есть определяют вид скептиков. Редко встречается слитная форма: *президенты-ковидскептики*.

В этом случае ***ковид*** – это приложение, выраженное существительным, а ***ковид-скептик***  можно рассматривать как словосочетание (приложение + существительное).

Одиночное приложение пишется через дефис, причем обычно приложение стоит после определяемого слова  (*инженер-конструктор, мороз-воевода, ученик-отличник)*, но в данном случае приложение стоит **в препозиции** (там иногда возможно раздельное письмо: *старик сторож*).  Однако это **несклоняемое** слово (сравнить: *царь- колокол, золото-старушка*), поэтому написание дефисное.

2. Если считать, что ***ковид*** – это иноязычный формант, то дефисное написание объясняется в  орфографическом разделе (сравнить: *гамма-излучение*). В этом случае также явно **определительное** значение слова, с чем и связано написание через дефис.

**Слитное** письмо иноязычных элементов встречается часто (*метеосводка, биостанция*), но там у нас новое понятие,  для обозначения которого требуется новое слово, а не определение к уже существующему.

**Приложение**

Орфография:  § 38. Сложные существительные  http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=48#pp48

Пунктуация: § 19. Обособленные приложения http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp1